# Linux - Replacing a string in a file

Tags: linux, string, unix, replace

I have a file that contains the following portion of text:

```
--------------begin------------------              
uncomment for static IP   
iface eth0 inet static  
address 192.168.0.202  
netmask 255.255.255.0  
network 192.168.0.0  
gateway 192.168.0.200  

iface eth1 inet dhcp   
---------------end---------------------
```

I would like to change the IP address into: 192.168.151.23
The text after being changed looking like this:

```
--------------begin------------------  
uncomment for static IP   
iface eth0 inet static  
address 192.168.151.23  
netmask 255.255.255.0  
network 192.168.0.0  
gateway 192.168.0.200  

iface eth1 inet dhcp  
---------------end---------------------
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: open the file in a text editor, and make the changes.. I like `pico` or `nano` in Linux

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. What is the pattern that should be looked for?  Exactly 192.168.0.202, or is there some more general pattern?  Similarly with the replacement: is it always 192.168.151.23, or is there an algorithm for deducing the new IP address from the old?  Or is there a table of old and new addresses somewhere (in a file)? If there wasn't some generality required, you'd simply use the new file you've specified, so you must have some deeper requirement, but you've not stated it, so we can't easily guess what's going on.

Comment: Also, there are a myriad questions on SO that are very closely related; many of those will have an outline of the answer you need.